Having Problems with Multiple Contract Methods calls
i'm makin 3 method calls at same time in web3j like:
contract.mint(mintParams).sendAsync()
contract.mint(mintParams).sendAsync()
contract.mint(mintParams).sendAsync()
The exception thrown is JsonRpcError with code -32000, and the message states "replacement transaction underpriced."
Upon investigation, I suspect that the issue may be related to nonce management, but I'm unsure how to resolve it. Could you please help me correct this?
full code here:
  Web3j web3j = Web3j.build(new HttpService(RPC));
    Credentials credentials = Credentials.create(PRIVATE_KEY);
    long chainID = Long.parseLong(CHAIN_ID);
    

    BigInteger maxPriorityFeePerGas = BigInteger.valueOf(5000000000L);
    BigInteger maxFeePerGas = BigInteger.valueOf(20000000000L);

    StaticEIP1559GasProvider gasProvider = new StaticEIP1559GasProvider(chainID, maxFeePerGas, maxPriorityFeePerGas, Contract.GAS_LIMIT);

    TransactionManager transactionManager = new RawTransactionManager(web3j, credentials, chainID);

    AuthLink contract = AuthLink.load(CONTRACT_ADDRESS, web3j,transactionManager ,gasProvider);
    MintParams mintParams = getMintParams(PUBLIC_KEY, ethCertificateDTO);
    TransactionReceipt receipt = null;
    try{
        if(flag){
            receipt = contract.mint(mintParams).send();
        }else{
            receipt = contract.mint(mintParams).sendAsync()
            receipt = contract.mint(mintParams1).sendAsync()
            receipt = contract.mint(mintParams2).sendAsync()
        }
            
    }
    catch (UnknownHostException | ClientConnectionException e) {
        throw new BlockchainConnectionFailedExcepion("Conexão com a rede blockchain falhou.");
    }
    catch (TransactionException e){
        throw new ETHCertificateCreationFailed("Erro na transação de criação do certificado: "+ e.getMessage());
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        throw new GenericBlockchainException(e);
    }
    return buildTransactionReceipt(receipt);

obs:im a new bee at web3j
